# How to select li element in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

[image]

I want to select "India (+91)" from dropdown

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I would recommend also to have a look at https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/find-element-selenium/ there you can find good tricks / tipps about automation testing, in my case it helped. Hope in yours also..

Answer (score 4):

Use the below code:

```
WebElement countryUL= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='country_id']/ul"));
List<WebElement> countriesList=countryUL.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for (WebElement li : countriesList) {
if (li.getText().equals("India (+91")) {
     li.click();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, just you have to use **Select method** in WebDriver.

```
    WebElement countrydropdown=driver.findElement(By.id("country_id"));
    Select country=new Select(countrydropdown);
    country.selectByVisibleText("India (+91)");
```

Comment: Hi don't think select will work with non select tags. you can use  select only with <select> tag i believe